# Can I add elements to the aps payload sent by the Bluemix IBM Push Notifications service?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm successfully using Bluemix Push to send notifications via the REST interface to an iOS app with a simple string alert message.  That works fine.

Now I would like to send a more complex message where alert is a dictionary and has a sibling "category" element per [The Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1).

Is this possible with Bluemix Push? Whenever I try to deviate from the basic structure, I get `"Bad Request - Invalid JSON"`.

Answer (score 1):

After much head-scratching, I finally picked up a hint from https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/t_advanced_notifications.html#t_push_badge_sound_payload and figured out that since the category field is unique to APNS, what I needed to send is

```
    "settings" : {
        "apns"   : {
            "category" : "myCategory"
        }
```

Comment: As a tip for future JSON construction, you can find all the acceptable JSON options @ https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/ . Select show messages, and whichever endpoint you desire. Then click on the greyed out "Model" button within the "body" parameter, right next to "Model Schema" and all the JSON options will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

@DSchultz_mo I was having issues to find the documentation but I finally found it, so if you go to https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#/ you can use swagger to register your device and send notification and the  magic button is  in model there is more details for sendMessageBody [image]

[image]